# Car jerks when shifting from Reverse to Drive

Tags: toyota, transmission, automatic-transmission, yaris

Recently, my car started jerking when the drive stick is shifted from 'R' to 'D' position. This doesn't happen when shifting between other positions (not even D to R) or when I switch between gears just after starting the vehicle.

For example, after reversing the vehicle and then when I'm shifting to 'D' to start driving, it starts the forward motion with a jerk, like the vehicle tripped over something.

I have consulted the local Toyota dealer, and their approach is to replace the entire gear box. Since it's costly, I'm wondering whether this can be fixed by replacing only few particular parts. Contacted few individual mechanics, but would like to know from anyone's experience what's the issue and potential fix. So, I will have some sort of understanding on what's going on.

*Note: Car is a 2007 manufactured Toyota Belta. Has a mileage around 110,000 Km.*

Comment: Further note, transmission fluid has been replaced when the mileage was around 92,000 km. Not sure about when the first replacement happened since the records weren't available from the previous owner.

Comment: I'm thinking engine mounts.  Open the hood and have someone watch the engine while you shift between gears.  If the engine is moving excessively, the engine mounts need to be replaced.

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level? It could be a bit low. I'd try a fluid change before replacing the box, that's for sure. 20,000 km is pretty low for a transmission fluid change but it's not unheard of.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you at a complete stop with your foot on the brake when shifting into Drive? Or are you still rolling backward? Also, is the engine idle correctly set (if it is too high it may cause an abrupt shift)? Is the transmission fluid level correct?

Comment: @CharlieRB vehicle is at complete stop when I'm trying to shift the gears. I'm not exactly sure what "engine idle correctly set" means. Could you please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: Without your foot on the accelerator, what is the engine speed? Does it seem higher than normal?

Answer (score -1):

I have 2010 Lexus LS 460 and it did the same thing when the engine cold in the morning.  Shift to R and then to D, it shift pretty hard.  What I did to avoid this was shift from R to N and hold it for 1 second before shift to D and the problem gone.  The shifting doesn't jerking anymore.